# Get caret position in Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caret

**Note:** I had tried other answers related to this question. But not get the solution.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjalray89/gp5pvsvf/6/)

My code is in this fiddle which i have tried but not get the result.

I want to insert label at the **cursor position** and **`label`** **should not be editable**.

I want **cross browser** solution for this code.